# Псевдо корзина заказов на java

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, jstl

Такая ситуацию, есть страница на которой  (*циклом в jsp* ) располагаются объекты(*имею цвет вес и цену  и кнопку add*).Как мне при нажатии кнопки add(ну или другие варианты)  пометить этот объект что бы в последствии при нажатии кнопки 
*сформировать заказ*,  помеченые объекты вернулись обратно на сервер, и сохранились в сессии что бы пользователь смог продолжить покупку в любой момент ?

Answer (score 0):

Создайте в бд таблицу с временными заказами, сохраняйте данные о заказе туда. Далее при открытии странице с этими заказами конкретного пользователя, просто их выгружайте и отображайте на странице.